# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::FormatError)

Tags: rubygems

I build a gem of myself ,but I can't push it to rubugems when I command,

> gem push hola-1.2.0.gem -V
>
> GET https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz 302 Moved Temporarily
>   GET https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz 200 OK
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::FormatError)
>       No such file or directory - hola-1.2.0.gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the name of gem is used,so I changed a new name and it's ok